# SQL: Combine results of queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables as such:

| StudentID | Email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | him@school.edu |
| 2 | her@school.edu |

| Book Title | Borrowed By (Student ID) | Borrowed Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Some Book | 13 | 10/10/2021 |
| Other Book | 456 | 10/15/2021 |

I want to make a single SQL query to return the email of the student and borrowed date for a specific book title.

Something like

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    student_table
WHERE
    StudentID = (SELECT 
            StudentID
        FROM
            borrowed_table
        WHERE
            BookTitle = 'Some Book');
```

but this would only return the Email. I want to return the borrowed date as well.
How can I combine the results of both queries?

Can this be done without specifying the columns (UNION of *) ?

Comment: use a Join on studentID

Comment: It is helpful to show the actual output you want to see as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join both tables

```
SELECT 
    st.*,bt.`Borrowed Date`
FROM
    student_table st
    INNER JOIN borrowed_table bt ON st.StudentID = bt.StudentID
WHERE
  bt.BookTitle = 'Some Book';
```

Answer (score 0):

Select st.BookTitle, st.BorrowedBy, bt.BorrowedDate
from Student_table st inner join
borrowed_table bt on st.StudentID = bt.StudentID
where bt.BookTitle = 'Some book title'